# Metricbeat modules

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

Why are there two modules in metric beat for ES

1. Elasticsearch
2. Elasticsearch-pack

Both has same configurations in the modules.d directory.

Kibana page for Elasticsearch module suggests to use Elasticsearch module.

But documentation of Elasticsearch modules suggests the later one. [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/7.12/metricbeat-module-elasticsearch.html)

> Alternatively, run metricbeat modules disable elasticsearch and metricbeat modules enable elasticsearch-xpack.

It's so confusing. I think that if I need to use ES-wtih-Xpack, then the later module. But from 6.7.0 onwards, ES ships basic features of x-pack with open source one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration are almost the same, the `elasticsearch-xpack` has the option `xpack.enabled: true`, which is not present in the `elasticsearch` module, and in the `elasticsearch-xpack` modulo you also do not specify any metricsets.

If you are using the monitoring UI in Kibana, then you should use the `elasticsearch-xpack` module, which will collect the metrics that kibana needs.

If you are not using the monitoring UI in Kibana, or are not even using Kibana and just want to collect the metrics, then you need to use the `elasticsearch` module and specify the metricsets that you want to collect.

The `elasticsearch-xpack` is just the `elasticsearch` module without any `metricsets` configured and with the option `xpack.enabled: true`.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. If I don't view it in kibana, where will that elasticsearch module ship the metrics. To anywhere where output.*** is specified in metricbeat.yml?